# Android java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError SherlockFragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, actionbarsherlock, android-fragmentactivity

What i want to do:
I want to start a new SherlockFragmentActivity.(mysecondactivity).

```
public class mysecondactivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity
```

I am doing that from a normal Activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, mysecondactivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Sooo i am getting the following Error:

> 06-12 23:48:20.870: E/AndroidRuntime(18865): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.test.mysecodnactivity

(Error is pointing at the creation of the Intent above)

But if i change "extends SherlockFragmentActivity" to "extends Activity" the Error is gone.

Comment: There's not enough information in here. You need to show the package declaration for mysecondactivity.

Comment: It is in the same package as the firstactivity. However the answer below solved it already. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with your project setup. Are you sure you have added the sherlock library to your project?

If you are using eclipse and added actionbarsherlock project to your workspace:
right click your own project -> properties -> android ->Library -> Add -> Choose your Actionbarsherlock project

then in the same window
java build path -> Libraries -> be sure actionbarsherlock can be found under Android Dependencies or Android Private Libraries (im not sure)

then go to the Order and Export tab -> Android Private Libraries AND Android Dependencies has to be checked.

Then it should work.

Comment: Thanks. the last point helped :) Everything was ok besides that "Android Dependencies" was unchecked in order and export tab